Proper use of the writeRaster() function in R
Good morning,
I am attempting to use the writeRaster() function in R to create a .tif file of a predictive raster. However, the output .tif file if quite different from that shown in R.
When I create the raster using the predict() and rast() function:
Det_Rast_df$predShan <- terra::predict(mean_Shanm_lmer_bestFit, newdata = Det_Rast_df, type = "response", allow.new.levels = TRUE)

pred_Shan_rast <- terra::rast(Det_Rast_df[,c("x","y", "predShan")], type = 'xyz')

plot(pred_Shan_rast, axes = F)


I receive a rather nice looking raster in the R "plots" window:
However, when I use the writeRaster() function:
terra::writeRaster(pred_Shan_rast, "pred_Shan_raster.tif", filetype = "GTiff", overwrite = T)


The output is as such:


It looks like you might have subset desired values out prior to writeRaster call, though hard to tell without a head(Det_rast_df), and on writing that head( request wonder why your <- predict doesn`t go to a rast object rather than burying it within a data.frame? What are the values of 'pred_Shan_raster.tif, 0/1?

It seems that what you are showing is the result obtained with a graphics viewer that assumes this to be a standard TIFF file.
However, with writeRaster, you are writing a GeoTIFF. That is a tiff file with a bunch of additional information about the location. The interpretation of the cell (pixel) values is also different from a standard TIFF file.
You can see that the file is correct by doing
plot(rast("pred_Shan_raster.tif"))

The best way to write a graphics file is to use use a sequence like png(); plot(); dev.off(). It is also possible to use the PNG or JPEG driver (format) with terra::writeRaster  .
